# Extending GenericRepository to be used in a Controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, architecture

I've been searching lately for ways that can improve my code quality, and for an architecture that I can use and that can make my code reusable and clean as much as possible.

At this point here is the architecture that I've implemented so far :

IBaseRepository.cs :

```
    public interface IBaseRepository<T>
    {
        IQueryable<T> Get(GlobalParams itemParams);
        Task<T> GetByID(int id);
        Task<T> Insert(T entity);
        Task Delete(int id);
        Task Delete(T entity);
        Task Update(T entity);
        Task<int> Count();
    }
```

IClientRepository.cs

```
public interface IClientRepository : IBaseRepository<Client>
{
    Task<int> CountCompanyClients(GlobalParams globalParams);
}
```

My BaseController.cs

```
    public class BaseController<T> : ControllerBase where T : class
            {
                protected readonly ConcreetDataContext _context;
                protected readonly IBaseRepository<T> _repo;
                protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;
        
                public BaseController(ConcreetDataContext context, IBaseRepository<T> repo)
                {
                    _context = context;
                    _repo = repo;
                    _dbSet = _context.Set<T>();
                }
                
                // Other Methodds...
             }
```

ClientController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientController : BaseController<Client>
    {
        private readonly IClientRepository _clientRepo;
        public ClientController(ConcreetDataContext context, IBaseRepository<Client> repo) : base(context, repo)
        {
            
        }

        [HttpGet("countCompanyClients")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<int>> CountCompanyClients([FromQuery] ClientParams clientParams)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

As you can see I want to use the custom method from IClientRepository : CountCompanyClients.

1. I want to know what is the best way to use the method from my repository, and how to register the repository.
2. Is it important to use services to move business logic from the repository? and why it is so important?
3. I want also to take this opportunity to ask about why do we inject interfaces instead of the class.

If you have any remarks about this architecture and some advice I'd really want to know about them.

Comment: Why are you injecting both a DbContext and a Repository? That makes no sense. However, this is both too broad and opinionated.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you are right in fact, I should not inject context in my controller, I'm just refactoring my code at the moment, so I'll remove it afterwards after its use is pointless. Thank you for pointing this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CountCompanyClients()` is not a part of the repository pattern. As your `IBaseRepository` interface suggests, this pattern is to act like a basic collection over some objects.

What you have in `CountCompanyClients` is really a *query*, so I think you should have a separate architecture for implementing that. It could be as complex or as simple as you like.

```
public interface IQuery<TArgs, TResult>
{
    public TResult Execute(TArgs args);
}

public class CountCompanyClientsQuery : IQuery<CountCompanyClientsArgs, int>
{
    private DataContext _db;
    
    public CountCompanyClients(DataContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    
    public int Execute(CountCompanyClientsArgs args)
    {
        return _db.CompanyClients.Count(x => x.CompanyId == args.CompanyId);
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this make make code more complex? What I have done is that I've injected IClientRepository interface as a new property in my ClientController, because what if I have a lot of other custom methods in my ClientRepository ?

Comment: You might think it makes your overall code more complex, but it's only introducing one new pattern, meanwhile your code all benefits from Clean Code principles like SRP etc.

Comment: Thank you so much @Neil I guess this is the best way